# BASH grep pattern filename in end of line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just started bash and i am doing a search script that search for files and grep a pattern. Simple idea:

```
find $HOME -type f | grep  $1
```

In the current script i match everything that contains $1 (files and directories). I only want to match the pattern in the filename, i don't want to match the directories in the path. I tried lots of advanced expressions with symbols like "/.*^$" etc.. to grep in a specific part but honestly for a new user is being a bit hard.

Cut tool is not an option because i want the path of the file.

EDIT:

Correct Example:

```
$ ./search test
/home/user/documents/test.txt
/home/user/downloads/blahtestblah.py
```

Incorrect example:

```
$ ./search test
/home/user/test/whatever.txt
```

In the incorrect example grep matched the keyword in the path, matching a directory.

Comment: Can you show us an actual sample input and the output you expect out of it

Comment: use `basename` like `find $HOME -type f | grep  $(basename $1)` , but why you are doing like that ? not efficent way, `find` can do it without `grep`

Comment: Ty but didn't work. I am using grep because the keyword must be inside the name, not just the name itself. Edited with some examples

Comment: you should work your way thru a find tutorial, I think you're missing some of its basic features. Maybe http://grymoire.com/Unix/Find.html` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`^` matches the *beginning* of the string. Try:

```
find $HOME -type f | grep  "/.*$1$"
```

You could also use the `-regex` switch to `find` instead of piping the output to `grep`:

```
find $HOME -type f -regex ".*$1$"
```

Comment: But almost!, your first script is matching in the extension part. For example if i do "./search py" returns all the .py files.